# Assign UITableView content to prepare segue in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, segue

I faced an issue when trying to build a tableView and use a segue to prepare the next `UIViewController` screen.

So, from screen A to screen B, on screen B I need to display the info that will be determined by the data user pressed on screen A.

Here is the code in screen A the ViewController:

```swift
extension VehicleListToInsureViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //print(vehicleList[indexPath.row].vehicleName)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.segueVehicleListToPolicyList, sender: self)
    
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! PolicyOptionsViewController
        destinationVC.vehicleName = vehicleList[indexPath.row].vehicleName
        
    }
    
}
```

I use an extension to use the `UITableViewDelegate`, but this line:

```
destinationVC.vehicleName = vehicleList[indexPath.row].vehicleName
```

throws errors:

> ```
> indexPath is unresolved identifier...
> ```

How can I fix it? I know it's two functions, that's why I can't use `indexPath`, but how can resolve this problem to get the data from `vehicleList`?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass to the index path (or whatever else you want, really) to `prepareForSegue` via the `sender` parameter:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.segueVehicleListToPolicyList, 
             sender: indexPath) // <---- !!
```

In `prepareForSegue`, you can try to cast the `sender` to `IndexPath`:

```
if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? PolicyOptionsViewController,
   let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
   destinationVC.vehicleName = vehicleList[indexPath.row].vehicleName
}
```

Alternatively, directly pass `vehicleList[indexPath.row].vehicleName` as the sender, and cast to `String`:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.segueVehicleListToPolicyList, 
             sender: vehicleList[indexPath.row].vehicleName)
// ...
if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? PolicyOptionsViewController,
   let vehicleName = sender as? String {
   destinationVC.vehicleName = vehicleName
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sweeper for your response,

using your first solution, I got a Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'PolicyOptionsViewController' error for the line `if let destinationVC = .....`, 

The 2nd solution, if I modify the performSegue function as you suggested, what should I do with the prepare for Segue function? too many errors occur if I modify the performSegue function as you suggested....

Comment: @Yudi Oops! Had some typos. Replace `!?` with `?`.

Comment: Works now, appreciate it !

Answer (score 2):

Rather than connecting the segue from the **controller** connect it from the **table view cell** to the destination controller.

The benefit is you can delete

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //print(vehicleList[indexPath.row].vehicleName)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.segueVehicleListToPolicyList, sender: self)

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

---

When `prepare(for` is called the `sender` parameter contains the `cell` and you can ask the table view for its index path

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == Constants.segueVehicleListToPolicyList,
          let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
          let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
    
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! PolicyOptionsViewController
    destinationVC.vehicleName = vehicleList[indexPath.row].vehicleName
    
}
```

Comment: Hi Vadian, Thanks for your response.

if I delete the didSelectRowAt, then we don't have the performSegue function. When I click the cell, it does not take to me the next screen... so I think I still need to keep the performSegue. 

the prepare for segue func you provide does not have error... but the vehicleName doesn't get passed right value, it's nil...

Comment: Please reread the first sentence of my answer. You have to reconnect the segue in Interface Builder.

Comment: yep, my bad! Thanks mate!